# how to get data from a form("multipart/form-data") with springMvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

## how to get data from a form("multipart/form-data") with springMvc?

i want to upload a file(a photo),so the type of form is 'multipart/form-data'

## but i found that springMVC cannot map data(in the form) into the property of User,I know i should use multipartFile to accept the picture,but how can other data in the form be mapped into object User automatically ?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" type="post" action="....">
    <input type"file" name="photo"/>
    <input type"text" name="username"/>
     .....
</form>

@RequestMapping("...")
public String editUser(User user,MultipartFile multipartFile){
.....
}
```

I get a 400 bad request error,so does anyone know how to achieve it? thanks a lot if someone help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:-

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" type="post" action="....">
<input type"file" name="photo"/>
<input type"text" name="username"/>
 .....
</form>
```

add model attribute on this page and use it in 
your controller like this:-

```
@RequestMapping("...")
public String editUser(@RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile photo,
 @ModelAttribute("your model attribute") User user){
.....
}
```

Comment: Hey I am getting Required request part 'photo' is not present error message